# SpringBeans and Inheritance results in NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, websphere-8

So I have basically this setup:

I have an application running on a WAS 8.5.5, it synchronises our CRM to an EMS using this projects web-API.
I'm in the charge of creating a webfrontend to maintain those synchronisations. To display the database values I'm just printing the the database table on a html.

I have created a small structure, which you will understand when getting to the codesnippets.

The workflow of this project is basically to poll the synchronisation, and collect the resulting data in a database. My frontend is responsible for showing the collected data.
For this I'm using a pojo's childclasses to correspond to the client, since my frontend is able to take any sort of a grid inheriting from the parentclass.

The childs are inheriting from the parentclass Grid:

```
public class Grid {
    private List<String> columnNames;
    private List<Page> pages; //this are custom pages consisting of a specific amount of tablerows
    private int currentPageIndex;
    private boolean isSortedDescending;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

The childclasses are:

HistoryGrid:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class HistoryGrid extends Grid{
    private HistoryAttributes sortedBy; //this is a enumvalue

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

and HistoryDetailGrid:

```
@Component
public class HistoryDetailGrid extends Grid {
    private long historyEntryId; //to map the details to its Histories
    private HistoryDetailAttributes sortedBy; //this is a enumvalue

    //Getters and Setters
```

Both grids represent databasetables and it is a 1:n-relation, each history entry has n history-detail entries.

Than I have my Businesslogic classes which follow the same inheritance-pattern:

GridService:

```
public abstract class GridService { 
    Grid grid;

    public void nextPage() {
        ... //this needs the grid-variable
    }

    public void lastPage() {
        ... //this needs the grid-variable
    }

    //Getter and Setter

    public abstract void initGrid();
    public abstract void createPages();
    public abstract void filter(Object property, String valueFilteredBy);
    public abstract void sort(Object property, boolean isDescending);
}
```

The HistoryGridService:

```
@Service
public class HistoryGridService extends GridService {   
    @Autowired
    private HistoryGrid hg;

    @Override
    public void createPages() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void initGrid() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(Object property, String valueFilteredBy) {
        ... 
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(Object property, boolean isDescending) {
        ...
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

And the HistoryDetailGridService:

```
@Service
public class HistoryDetailGridService extends GridService {
    @Autowired
    HistoryDetailGrid hdg;

    public void initGridByCsv() {       
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void initGrid() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void createPages() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(Object property, String valueFilteredBy) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(Object property, boolean isDescending) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I removed all the unnecessery attributes and logic for simplicity, no need to focus on this.

When starting my application I'm getting this exception:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [dispatcher] in application [MyProjectEAR]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'historyGridService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'grid'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.me.my_project.web.Grid' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: historyDetailGrid,historyGrid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:345)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:642)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1452)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1034)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5482)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.me.my_project.web.Grid' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: historyDetailGrid,historyGrid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 46 more
```

The exception basically says my HistoryGridService is not able to inject the Grid, which is a bit confusing since the HistoryGridService shouldn't know anything about the grid becouse it's using the Grids child -> HistoryGrid.
Neither should Springs IoC-Container know anything about the Grid, it's not a bean.

So how is it possible this exception occours and how am I able to fix it?

My expectation is that the HistoryGridService should be able to inject the HistoryGrid instead of the Grid.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**
**@M. Deinum's approach**

So I made this:

```
@Service
public class HistoryGridService extends GridService {
    public class Config {
        @Bean
        public HistoryGrid historyGrid() {
            return new HistoryGrid();
        }
    }

    private final HistoryGrid HG;

    public HistoryGridService(HistoryGrid hg) {
        super(hg);
        HG = hg;
    }

    ...
}
```

Please take note of the fact that I cannot make hg final becouse it will be updated in each method.

and in GridService:

```
public abstract class GridService {
    private Grid grid;

    public GridService(Grid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }
```

However this approach results in this exception:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:345)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:642)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1452)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1034)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5482)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5698)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.me.my_project.services.HistoryDetailGridService$Config': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'historyDetailGridService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'historyDetailGridService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 69 more
```

**EDIT 2**
**Fix**

Following @M. Deinum recommendation I was able to fix this issue.
Both childclasses have now a parameterised constructor which accepts either the instance of HistoryGrid or HistoryDetailGrid. Those will be implicitly injected from the IoC-Container when the beans are created.

```
public abstract class GridService { 
    private final Grid GRID;

    public GridService(Grid grid) {
        GRID = grid;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
@Service
public class HistoryDetailGridService extends GridService {
    private final HistoryDetailGrid HDG;

    public HistoryDetailGridService(HistoryDetailGrid hdg) {
        super(hdg);
        HDG = hdg;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Both your classes are `Grid` instances (they extend it) and as your superclass needs a `Grid` it cannot fulfill wiring the dependencies into your base `GridService` as it finds 2 beans that adhere to being a `Grid`. To fix. Remove `@Autowired` from your fields, make them `private final` and use constructor injection, and call `super(grid)` to inject it into your super class as well.

Comment: how i understood:
- implement a constructor in GridService -> public GridService(Grid grid)
- remove Autowired from HistoryGridService.hg
- override HistoryGridServices default constructor and just call super(hg)
- also create a inner class annotated with Configuration which has a getter annotated with Bean which return a new HistoryGrid(),

but how will be the HistoryGrid injected into the HistoryGridService when removing the Autowired annotation?

i followed this https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: Just add it to the constructor... As there is a single constructor spring will detect it and use it for autowiring. You don't even need the `@Autowired` that way.

Comment: sry im kind of confused right now, add what to which constructor since i have two new constructors:
GridService(Grid grid) { this.grid = grid } and HistoryGridService() { super.(hg) }

Comment: `HistoryGridService(HistoryGrid hg)` that should first call `super(hg)` then do `this.hg=hg`. Where `this.hg` should be `final`. The same for the `grid` field in the super class.

Comment: check the post for my answer

Comment: Remove the `@Configuration` from your service. Your beans are already `@Component` annotated and thus detected by the component scanning. You are making things overly complex. Also why wouldn't you be able to make it `final`? As long as you don't assign a new instance it works you can change anything inside it.

Comment: still the same exception occours

Comment: If you removed the `@Configuration` classes from your services getting the same exception is impossible.

Comment: the exception remains the same but this time at the HistoryDetailGrid, where I used the same approach

Comment: As stated remove the `@Configuration` classes. Either make them dedicated classes, but that will lead to errors (2 instances of a `HistoryGrid` will be created, due to 1 from the configuration the other being scanned). The fact that you have a non-static public embedded classes leads to this erorr (as it requires an instance of the service to be instantiated, but a service needs the bean from the configuration class, chicked/egg problem).

Comment: I mean I did remove the ```@Configuration``` from HistoryGridService.Config and from HistoryDetailGridService.Config
therefore the instance of HistoryDetailGridService.Config is independant from HistoryDetailGridService in terms of DependencyInjection. But the exceptions still remains.

Comment: You should remove the config class not just the annotation completely as it will result in 2 beans being registered.

Comment: Ok but where do I get the beans from than?

I'm not using ```@Autowired```, but rather initialising it in the constructor. The instantiation happens in the IoC-Container which is out of my control, so how will be the HistoryDetailGrid passed into the constructor of HistoryDetailGridService?

Comment: As I explained in the comment, due to the `@Component` annotation it will be detected and an instance created.

Comment: Ok finally its working, I really appretiate your patience with me you really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Grid class is extended by two classes (HistoryGrid and HistoryDetailGrid) in this case, Spring will not know which one of the two implementations to inject: to differentiate bean name on creation a qualifier need to be specified.

```
--------------------------
public class Grid {
    ......
    ......
    //added this method to show which implementation is invoked
    public void printClassName(){
        System.out.println("In Grid");
    }

}

@Component("historyDetailGrid")
public class HistoryDetailGrid extends Grid {

    ......
    ......
    @Override  
    public void printClassName(){
        System.out.println("Inside historyDetail Grid");
    }
}

@Component("historyGrid")
public class HistoryGrid extends Grid {

    .......
    .......
    @Override  
    public void printClassName(){
        System.out.println("Inside history Grid");
    }
}


public abstract class GridService {
    //Removed grid declaration and get grid object as method param
    public void nextPage(Grid grid) {
    }

    public void lastPage(Grid grid) {
    }

    /**
     * To show which implementation class is invoked from main method
     */
    public abstract void printClassName();

    public abstract void createPages();

    public abstract void filter(Object property, String valueFilteredBy);

    public abstract void sort(Object property, boolean isDescending);
}

@Service("historyDetailGridService")
public class HistoryDetailGridService extends GridService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("historyDetailGrid")
    Grid hdg;

 @Override
    public void printClassName() {
        hdg.printClassName();
    }

 // other abstract methods
  .....
}

@Service("historyGridService")
public class HistoryGridService extends GridService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("historyGrid")
    private Grid hg;

   @Override
    public void printClassName() {
        hg.printClassName();
    }

 // other abstract methods
  .....
}

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.*"})
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("historyDetailGridService")
    GridService historyDetailGridService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("historyGridService")
    GridService historyGridService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void printClasses(){
        historyGridService.printClassName();
        historyDetailGridService.printClassName();
    }

}

----------------
output will be 
Inside history Grid
Inside historyDetail Grid
2019-10-09 21:34:31.356  INFO 3235 --- [           main] com.service.Main                         : Started Main in 1.439 seconds (JVM running for 1.791)
-----------------
```